# Calculate time duration between events

Tags: r, time, date-difference

I have the following data:

```
DateTime        |   Var1 |  Var2 |  var3 |  var4 |  %Var1 | level
-------------------------------------------------------------------
11/15/2016 6:11 |       0 |  0.94 |  0.65 |  1.14 | 0     | (0,5]
11/15/2016 6:12 |    0.70 | 29.98 |  9.01 | 30.01 | 0.53  | (0,5]
11/15/2016 6:13 |   35.08 | 152.23| 141.71| 103.7 | 26.57 | (5,30]
11/15/2016 6:14 |   69.05 | 137.97| 130.81| 101.54| 52.31 | (30,60]
11/15/2016 6:15 |   69.38 | 138.7 | 131.3 | 101.67| 52.56 | (30,60]
11/15/2016 6:19 |   80.63 | 140   | 134   | 126.45| 61.09 | (60,100]
11/15/2016 6:20 |   82.86 | 141.33| 136.09| 129.7 | 62.77 | (60,100]
11/15/2016 6:44 |   132.33| 206.18| 205.61| 205.64| 100.25| (100,500]
11/15/2016 6:45 |   128.75| 202.51| 197.69| 198.92| 97.53 | (60,100]
```

Columns for Datetime and Var1 - Var4 are present in the starting data.

%Var1 column is obtaining by calculating Var1 as a percentage of a pre-defined value. Then, the data in %var1 column is factored into different 'levels' (indicated by last column).
The levels may not always occur in an ordered fashion, i.e, (100,500] may be followed by (5,30], and so on.

I have to calculate the time interval spent in each of the different levels.
Hence the total time spent in the level (60,100] is from 6:19 to 6:44 and from 6:45 onwards to the next data point (not shown in table).

How to calculate this?

I found this related post [R Calculate time difference between events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32928044/r-calculate-time-difference-between-events) ; however, the rows contain data for the transition time points, whereas in my case, I have to ascertain whether the system is continuing in the same level or undergoing a transition by looking at the subsequent row data.

EDIT:
I have calculated the time difference between successive instances and added that as a column to the dataframe.

```
df <- data.frame(s$dateTime, s$Var1, s$Var2, s$Var3, s$Var4)       
df$Var5 <- df$s.Var1 * 100/NumericConstant
fac <- cut(df$Var5, c(-10, 5, 30, 60, 100, 500)) 
df <- cbind(df,fac)

c_time <- as.POSIXlt(df$DateTime )
timedur <- as.numeric(difftime(c_time[2:length(c_time)] , c_time[1:(length(c_time)-1)], tz = 'UTC'))
timedur <- append(timedur,'NA') ## add 'NA' at end, since length(timedur) is 1 short of the DF
df <- cbind(df,timedur)  ## add the time differences column to the dataframe
```

So now, my data looks like the following:

```
DateTime        |   Var1 |  Var2 |  var3 |  var4 |  %Var1 | level | timedur
-------------------------------------------------------------------
11/15/2016 6:11 |       0 |  0.94 |  0.65 |  1.14 | 0     | (0,5] | 60
11/15/2016 6:12 |    0.70 | 29.98 |  9.01 | 30.01 | 0.53  | (0,5] | 60
......... and so on
```

I want to check how long the system was in state (0,5] before it changed to (5,30], then how long it was in (5,30], then in (30,60] and so on.

Comment: Could you provide the code you used to try this yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a cross join and selecting the first row with a different level.

generate the data:

```
str <- '
DateTime        |   Var1 |  Var2 |  var3 |  var4 |  %Var1 | level
11/15/2016 6:11 |       0 |  0.94 |  0.65 |  1.14 | 0     | (0,5]
11/15/2016 6:12 |    0.70 | 29.98 |  9.01 | 30.01 | 0.53  | (0,5]
11/15/2016 6:13 |   35.08 | 152.23| 141.71| 103.7 | 26.57 | (5,30]
11/15/2016 6:14 |   69.05 | 137.97| 130.81| 101.54| 52.31 | (30,60]
11/15/2016 6:15 |   69.38 | 138.7 | 131.3 | 101.67| 52.56 | (30,60]
11/15/2016 6:19 |   80.63 | 140   | 134   | 126.45| 61.09 | (60,100]
11/15/2016 6:20 |   82.86 | 141.33| 136.09| 129.7 | 62.77 | (60,100]
11/15/2016 6:44 |   132.33| 206.18| 205.61| 205.64| 100.25| (100,500]
11/15/2016 6:45 |   128.75| 202.51| 197.69| 198.92| 97.53 | (60,100]
'

file <- textConnection(str)

df <- read.table(file, sep = "|", header = T)

df$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(df$DateTime , format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

Join the dataframe on itself to find the next DateTime with a different level.

```
library(dplyr)

nxt <- df %>% mutate(dummy = 1) %>%
  inner_join(df %>% 
              select(level, DateTime) %>% 
              rename(DateTimeNext = DateTime, levelNext = level) %>% 
              mutate(dummy=1), by='dummy') %>%
  # remove previous rows and the same level
  filter(DateTime < DateTimeNext, level != levelNext) %>% 
  # group data to use in row_number()
  group_by(DateTime) %>%
  # select first row with different level
  filter(row_number(DateTimeNext) == 1) %>%
  select(DateTime, DateTimeNext)

df %>% left_join(nxt)


# filter out overlapping rows

df %>% left_join(nxt) %>% group_by(DateTimeNext) %>% filter(row_number(DateTime) == 1) %>%
  mutate(timedur = DateTimeNext - DateTime)
```

result:

```
             DateTime   Var1   Var2   var3   var4 X.Var1      level        DateTimeNext timedur
               <dttm>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>     <fctr>              <dttm>  <time>
1 2016-11-15 06:11:00   0.00   0.94   0.65   1.14   0.00      (0,5] 2016-11-15 06:13:00  2 mins
2 2016-11-15 06:13:00  35.08 152.23 141.71 103.70  26.57     (5,30] 2016-11-15 06:14:00  1 mins
3 2016-11-15 06:14:00  69.05 137.97 130.81 101.54  52.31    (30,60] 2016-11-15 06:19:00  5 mins
4 2016-11-15 06:19:00  80.63 140.00 134.00 126.45  61.09   (60,100] 2016-11-15 06:44:00 25 mins
5 2016-11-15 06:44:00 132.33 206.18 205.61 205.64 100.25  (100,500] 2016-11-15 06:45:00  1 mins
6 2016-11-15 06:45:00 128.75 202.51 197.69 198.92  97.53   (60,100]                <NA> NA mins
```

Comment: Running the 'POSIXct' command on the DateTime column converts the values to 'NA'.   
The remaining code (without POSIXct) gave error as follows:     
    > nxt <- df %>% mutate(dummy = 1) %>%
    +   inner_join(df %>% 
    + .....
    .....
    +   select(DateTime, DateTimeNext)
    Error: cannot allocate vector of size 3.3 Gb
 
    > df %>% left_join(nxt)
    Error in tbl_vars(y) : object 'nxt' not found
    > df %>% left_join(nxt) %>% group_by(DateTimeNext) %>%  filter(row_number(DateTime) == 1)
    Error in tbl_vars(y) : object 'nxt' not found

Comment: I guess your data is too big for my approach. Another option is not use the `join` but use an `apply` to collect the correct data.